# Is this redundant code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, properties

I'm upgrading a system and am going through another developers code (ASP.NET in C#).

I came across this:

```
private ReferralSearchFilterResults ReferralsMatched
{
    get
    {
        if (Session[SESSION_REFERRAL_SEARCHFILTERRESULTS] == null || Session[SESSION_REFERRAL_SEARCHFILTERRESULTS].GetType() != typeof(ReferralSearchFilterResults))
            return null;
        else
            return (ReferralSearchFilterResults)Session[SESSION_REFERRAL_SEARCHFILTERRESULTS];
    }
    set
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            Session[SESSION_REFERRAL_SEARCHFILTERRESULTS] = value;
        }
        else if (value.GetType() == typeof(ReferralSearchFilterResults))
        {
            Session[SESSION_REFERRAL_SEARCHFILTERRESULTS] = value;
        }
    }

}
```

Is checking the type on the setter unnecessary? Surely, if I set the property to something other than a `ReferralSearchFilterResults` object, the code wouldn't even compile? Am I missing something or am I right to think this can be achieved just by using:

```
set
{
    Session[SESSION_REFERRAL_SEARCHFILTERRESULTS] = value;
}
```

Comment: :) I would be more worried why a property value is getting stored into a session variable. Unless I am missing something here.

Comment: This is bad practice IMO. Nobody likes smartass properties which decide on their own that they should not do what you asked them to do, and don't even notify you about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original code prevents any subclasses of ReferralSearchFilterResults from being set or get to or from the property. This is because `value.GetType()` will return the actual `Type` of the object referenced by `value`. If that Type is a subclass of ReferralSearchFilterResults, then it will not equals `typeof(ReferralSearchFilterResults)`.

I'm not sure of your context here, so I can't tell you whether that's correct behaviour or not. If it's intended behaviour, it does smell a bit dirty as it will silently ignore any assignments of subclasses. But I can't really judge without more context.

Comment: I didn't know that a subclass could be set to a property of type parent class, I thought it was the other way round - maybe I need to do a little further reading. Anyway, I've learnt something from this answer and have therefore accepted as the answer.

Comment: Properties aren't special in the way they handle inheritance and polymorphism. Just like a local variable or a field you can assign a subclass to a reference of its base type.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're right - the setter shouldn't compile if provided with something of that cannot be implicitly cast to a `ReferralSearchFilterResults`.

Answer (score 3):

For the `get` part, you can use

```
return Session[SESSION_REFERRAL_SEARCHFILTERRESULTS] as ReferralSearchFilterResults;
```

This returns the value if it can be casted to `ReferralSearchFilterResults`, otherwise `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Jamie you are correct. The Type check on the Setter is unnecessary in this case because `value` *must* be a ReferralSearchFilterResults.

One other change you might consider is using the `is` and `as` keywords in place of comparing `Type` objects.

```
private ReferralSearchFilterResults ReferralsMatched
{
    get
    {
        if (Session[SESSION_REFERRAL_SEARCHFILTERRESULTS] == null || !(Session[SESSION_REFERRAL_SEARCHFILTERRESULTS] is ReferralSearchFilterResults))
            return null;
        else
            return Session[SESSION_REFERRAL_SEARCHFILTERRESULTS] as ReferralSearchFilterResults;
    }
    set
    {
        Session[SESSION_REFERRAL_SEARCHFILTERRESULTS] = value;
    }

}
```

Comment: As noted by Rik, you could just use as in the getter.

Comment: @Nathan Taylor: I don't understand the exception part. You could write `FilterResults fr = null as FilterResults` and it wouldn't throw an exception. That's why you use the `as` keyword in the first place. Where exactly would this exception be thrown?

Comment: @Nathan: what is a "non-initialized" object, exactly? And which exception would be thrown, precisely?

Comment: @Nathan: but `Session` is a hashtable, not an array. It returns null when key is not found.

Comment: @Groo Hrrm, I was under the assumption Session was a IDictionary, not a Hashtable; but I guess I was wrong. *inserts foot in mouth*

Comment: Ok, it's not exactly a hashtable (it's an instance of HttpSessionState), but it behaves like one, it just returns null when key is not found. Nevermind, I just wanted to double check, I never checked what's underneath until now, but I had a feeling it behaves like a hashtable.

Answer (score 1):

Session variables are of type object, so you can store anything inside those. But in this case the setter itself prevents the programmer from assigned an other object type than ReferralSearchFilterResults and derived objects.
So the check, as you pointed out, itself is unneccessary. Additionally it does not let a programmer assign a object that derives from ReferralSearchFilterResults.

But I would use Session.Remove rather than just setting the variable to null, because the session variable would still exists in the http context if only set to null.

So:

> ```
> set
> {
>       if (value == null)
>             Session.Remove(SESSION_REFERRAL_SEARCHFILTERRESULTS);
>       else
>             Session[SESSION_REFERRAL_SEARCHFILTERRESULTS] = value;
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I can understand the type check in the get bit, but as you say, in the setter, you can't pass in anything that's not a ReferralSearchFilterResults, as the code would fail at the time of compilation.

(Could be some old habit, the other developer had)

Comment: Indeed, it looks like that guy used a lot of weakly typed languages.